# invoking native module throws "not recognised objc method" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit

I am invoking Healthkit through React Native's NativeModules.
I can get the Authorisation part to work.

healthkit.m:

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(requestAuthorization)
```

healthkit.swift:

```
        @objc
        func requestAuthorization() {
           let writeDataTypes : Set<HKSampleType> = [ HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
                                                      HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic)!,
                                                      HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic)!,
                                                      HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex)!,
                                                      HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)!,
                                                      HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!
                                                      ]
           
           let readDataTypes : Set = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic)!,
                                                HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.biologicalSex)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)!,
                                                HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!,
                                                HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.bloodType)!,
                                                HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.dateOfBirth)!]

                     
                     healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: writeDataTypes, read: readDataTypes) { (success, error) in
                       
                         if (self.healthStore.authorizationStatus(for: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)!) == .sharingAuthorized) {
                             print("Permission Granted to Access bloodGlucose")
                         } else {
                             print("Permission Denied to Access bloodGlucose")
                         }
                       
                         if !success {
                             // Handle the error here.
                         }
                     }
           }
```

[image]

But the Query part doesn't work and it throws the below error.
healthkit.m

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getHeartRate: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                                 rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

healthkit.swift:

```
              @objc
              func getHeartRate(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                                rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
                let heartRate = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)
                let startOfDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: startDate)
                let endOfDate = Calendar.current.endOfDay(for: endDate)
                print("dat:",startOfDate, endOfDate)
                let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDate, end: endOfDate, options: .strictStartDate)
                let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRate!, predicate: predicate, limit: 20, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
                            for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample] {
                   ..................

                  }
```

[image]

What is wrong with the above code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be it gets confused by the "get" prefix in the method?

1. Try to use a different name
2. Are you sure you are passing the right params?
3. Try to be more explicit with the compiler specifying exactly what the method signature should look on objc:

```
@objc(getHeartRate:rejecter:)
func getHeartRate(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock)
```